# Who to boot Ubuntu and load automatically the gnome GUI using WSL from Microsoft

Tags: boot, gnome

I am trying Ubuntu using WSL from Microsoft . This kind of installation is different from using VMware or VirtualBox because when I get in, Ubuntu responds me with the command line. I want to get in to the gnome GUI from de beginning. I installed gnome with the instruction "sudo apt install gnome" and typed "gnome" expecting to load the GUI but that was not the solution.  Can you help me so when I boot Ubuntu automatically load de GUI from gnome?

Comment: not very familiar with WSL but I don't think that's possible, or at least easy to do, however apparently you can run GUI apps with WSL2, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps